# How to run laravel queue job(with delay) current ,

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-queue

There are some jobs delay to tomorrow ,It work correctly and it should run in tomorrow. The code like this.

```php
$delayTo = now()->addDays(1);
ProcessSomeThing::dispatch($params)->delay($delayTo);
```

But I am required to add a extra function to run it immediately not wait to tomorrow;
How to do it?

### my idea but not sure is it good

Changing the 'jobs.available_at' column a good way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dispatchNow()`

try this without dealy `ProcessSomeThing::dispatchNow($params)`

it run the job without queuing in job table.

refrence : [Laravel Queue Synchronous-dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#synchronous-dispatching)

Answer (score 0):

```
app(\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher::class)->dispatchNow(new $job)
```

OR

Global is also available

```
dispatch_now(new $job)
```